# In Powershell get UPN from PC name

Tags: powershell, endpoint, intune

I'm stuck since some days about my script :

I receive a CSV List with some PC name that are in intune and AAD in Azure. From that list I want to know Which PC has Which Owners.

```
Connect-AzureAD
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Tools\chatelet.csv
$ObjectID=@()
foreach ($DisplayName in $csv){
    $DisplayName
    $ObjectID1 = get-AzureADDevice -Filter "DisplayName eq $DisplayName" | Select ObjectID | ft -HideTableHeaders
    $ObjectID1
    $objectID += $ObjectID1
}
$ObjectID
$ObjectID | Out-File -encoding UTF8 'C:\Tools\BulkObjectID.csv'

$csv2 = Import-Csv C:\Tools\BulkObjectID.csv
$Owners=@()
foreach ($UPN in $csv2){
    $DisplayName
    $Owners1 = Get-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner -ObjectId $UPN |select mail
    $Owners1
    $Owners += $Owners1
}
$Owners | Out-File -encoding UTF8 'C:\Tools\Owners.csv'
```

I got that error :

```
get-AzureADDevice : Error occurred while executing GetDevices 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Syntax error: character '{' is not valid at position 16 in 'DisplayName eq @{DisplayName=SUS-5CG1027Z61}'.
RequestId: d102bfb2-b991-4fd7-afc7-a78de251662c
DateTimeStamp: Thu, 04 Nov 2021 07:42:04 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
Au caractère Ligne:5 : 18
+ ... ObjectID1 = get-AzureADDevice -Filter "DisplayName eq $DisplayName" | ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureADDevice], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetDevice
```

Comment: It seems that in your variable `$DisplayName` is more than just the value of the displayname. As the errormessage states it contains `@{DisplayName=SUS-5CG1027Z61}`. So adapt your code that the variable only contains the name

Answer (score 0):

When importing a CSV file with `Import-Csv`, the result is an array of **objects** even if the csv file has only one column.

That means that you need to rewrite this:

```
$ObjectID=@()
foreach ($DisplayName in $csv){
    $DisplayName
    $ObjectID1 = get-AzureADDevice -Filter "DisplayName eq $DisplayName" | Select ObjectID | ft -HideTableHeaders
    $ObjectID1
    $objectID += $ObjectID1
}
```

into:

```
$ObjectID = foreach ($item in $csv){
    Write-Host $item.DisplayName
    # just output the result, it will be collected in variable $ObjectID
    Get-AzureADDevice -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($item.DisplayName)'" | Select-Object ObjectID
}
```

As you may have noticed, I have

- changed the variable name of the iterating variable from `$DisplayName` to `$item` to denote that each item has a **property** called `DisplayName`
- used a sub expression in the filter string `$($item.DisplayName)`
- Removed `ft -HideTableHeaders` because Format-Table is **for display purposes only** and should not be used if you need to process the results further
- Removed the array concatenation with `+=` as this is time and memory consuming (on each iteration the **complete** array has to be re-created in memory) and simply **capture** the results of the foreach loop in the variable `$ObjectID`

The same applies to the second part of your code.
Replace that with:

```
$Owners = foreach ($item in $csv2){
    # just output the result, it will be collected in variable $Owners
    Get-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner -ObjectId $item.ObjectID | Select-Object mail
}
```

Here, since you are reloading the csv from the earlier loop (which is not necessary actually because you still have that info in memory in variable `$ObjectID`), you need to use the correct header, so `ObjectID` instead of `UPN`.

Lastly, do **not** use `Out-File` to create a CSV file. Use

```
$ObjectID | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Tools\BulkObjectID.csv' -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

and

```
$Owners | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Tools\Owners.csv' -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

instead.